# How to have generics to specify a complex dynamic tree structure in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

I am working on trying to model scope (see my last few questions if curious), but I mostly had it modelled wrong I think. So I am trying again.

Basically, scope is like lexical scope. You can have these sorts of complex situations (not to mention the obvious situations like simple class, function, and module scope, etc.):

- functions within functions within functions, arbitrarily deep
- classes within functions within classes within functions, etc.
- conditional/if blocks within blocks, within functions, etc.
- loops within loops (with the others mixed in too)
- manual scope creation (like in javascript how you can simply add `{ ... }` to fork a new local scope).

So we have these types of scope (at least).

- module
- class
- function
- condition
- loop
- fork

The problem I am having is how to specify the type when the "parent" scope on some scope (which is of one of these scope types) can be of different types. For example, you might have this sort of parent tree structure (assume scope has a `data` property, which is a record with keys and values, and an optional `parent` property, pointing to the parent). I'll just show one possible parent hierarchy here:

```
loop
  loop
    condition
      condition
        loop
          function
            class
              module
```

As I try to model this, I do this:

```
type ScopeModuleType<T> = {
  // somehow this should accept arbitrary record structures
  // but we should be able to harden the type when necessary
  data: <T>
  parent?: undefined
}

type ScopeClassType<T> = {
  data: T
  // we can define classes in functions, like in JavaScript
  parent: ScopeModuleType | ScopeFuncionType
}

type ScopeFunctionType<T> = {
  // the local variables for the function
  data: T
  // now, how do I pass the generic types `T` to these parents???
  parent: ScopeFunctionType | ScopeLoopType | ScopeConditionType | ScopeClassType | ScopeModuleType
}

type ScopeLoopType<T> = {
  // the loop data is like index, item, key perhaps, etc.
  data: T
  // again, how to pass the generic types to these?
  parent: ScopeFunctionType | ScopeLoopType | ScopeConditionType
}

type ScopeConditionType<T> = {
  // the local variables in the if block
  data: T
  parent: ScopeFunctionType | ScopeLoopType | ScopeConditionType
}
```

So you see one glaring problem there, how do I specify the `parent` `data` structure? How do I pass in the generic types for the parent?

You might try optional generics, like this:

```
type ScopeConditionType<T, F = unknown, L = unknown, Condition = unknown> = {
  // the local variables in the if block
  data: T
  parent: ScopeFunctionType<F> | ScopeLoopType<L> | ScopeConditionType<C>
}
```

And then try and use it like this:

```
const conditionScope: ScopeConditionType<
  { foo: string },
  unknown,
  ScopeLoopType<{ index: number }>
> = {
  data: {
    foo: 'bar'
  },
  parent: {
    data: {
      index: 123
    }
  }
}
```

But that seems ugly and like a hack, number one. And number two, I want to type it so it captures the full possible tree of types in the chain:

```
loop
  loop
    condition
      condition
        loop
          function
            class
              module
```

So then, if I wanted to have access to `scope.parent.parent.parent.index`, I would have to do something like this:

```
const x: ScopeLoopType<
  ScopeLoopType<
    undefined,
    ScopeConditionType<
      undefined,
      undefined,
      ScopeConditionType<
        undefined
        ScopeLoopType<...>
      >
    >
  >
>
```

Am I going about this the right way? Is there a way to accomplish this sort of thing differently? Or is there a cleaner API so I don't have to have undefined/unknown generics skipped over in the generics' arguments? Like perhaps I can do something like this:

```
const x: ScopeLoopType<{ j: number }, {
  Loop: ScopeLoopType<{ i: number }>, {
    Condition: ScopeConditionType<{}, {
      Condition: ScopeConditionType<{ foo: string }, {
        Loop: ScopeLoopType<...>
      }>
    }>
  }>
}>
```

Basically at least with that, you could define the entire tree structure with optional generics and it would make somewhat a bit of sense. You only have to define the parents up as far as you wanted to.

How should I go about structuring/implementing this sort of type system? *(recursive type generics)*

Comment: I don’t have an answer, but ithis is interesting. What is the use of this?

Comment: The use is for building an AST builder.

Comment: I'm probably mistaken, but I think this might be related to a very old open issue for the addition of "higher kinded types" https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1213